# syncing folders between wine and windows for foobar2000

Tags: wine, media, foobar2000

I use foobar2000 on windows to manage and play my music and and looking to get foobar2000 working under wine on ubuntu. Ive gotten the program to run fine and am just looking for a way to not have to maintain two copies of my music files.

so I have my music on windows drive E:music, but wine creates a virtual C drive and im wondering if i can somehow link a folder on the virtual drive to a folder on the actual E drive so that the files are visible in the virtual environment.

Basically i wanna have 1 music collection and avoid having to double manage files on my linux and windows systems and would accept any tips for achieving this.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use symbolic links. Delete the location of the music in your wine installation, then make a symbolic link, as so:

```
ln -s ~/Music ~/.wine/drive_e/music
```

Modify that command as needed.

Comment: This is the type of idea im going for but lemme clarify. My drive E is on the same harddrive as my linux, but its a seperate partition outside of linux. im trying to access it through wine which only sees the default drive c it creates and also the linux root. Sorry if im being slow, im new to linux

Comment: Where is your drive e located at relative to / ? Are you able to access it within linux?

Comment: nvm, what you suggested worked just fine:) thanks for the help!